# What is the file I have to debug to know how Magento load all file di.xml from all core module and custom module?

Tags: magento2, xml, di.xml

I understand that Magento will read all di.xml files and the output will be an array.

I want to know where this code is so I can debug and dig deeper into it.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, everything defined in `di.xml` will be processed when you perform the `setup:di:compile`, which generates and puts them into `generated/code/*` directories.

You can set breakpoint from `app/bootstrap.php` then inspect `$app` instance while debugging.